# Why does the parameter b have a type a in this example?

Tags: f#

I'm looking into [aether library](https://github.com/xyncro/aether/blob/master/src/Aether/Aether.fs) and noticed this

```
 type Lens<'a,'b> =
    ('a -> 'b) * ('b -> 'a -> 'a)

 static member (^=) (Set, (_, s): Lens<'a,'b>) =
            fun (b: 'b) ->
                s b : 'a -> 'a
```

In the ^= function, b parameter if of type 'b in the lambda. However, in the lamda body, why is b type of 'a now?

Comment: why do you think so?

Comment: @FoggyFinder i'm not sure. that's why i'm asking.

Comment: I mean why do you think that `b` has type 'a? btw, can we continue in the [F# chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, in the lamda body, why is b type of 'a now?

It is not.

`b` is an input which is typed `'b`, as shown in `fun (b: 'b) ->`.

We can rewrite that member without the matches, and using a locally defined function, like so:

```
static member (^=) (Set, lens: Lens<'a,'b>) =
    // Pattern match to extract out the 2nd portion of the lens, which is a function: 'b -> 'a -> 'a
    let (_,s) = lens

    // Define a function that takes a 'b and returns a new function of type: 'a -> 'a
    let fn (b: 'b) : 'a -> 'a =
        s b // this just partially applies s with the input "b"
    fn // Return the function
```

Basically, the `(Set, (_,s))` in the argument list binds "s" to the 2nd portion of a `Lens<'a,'b>`, or a function typed `('b -> 'a -> 'a)`. Above, I've broken that out to be more explicit, and done this extraction in its own binding.

The member then returns a locally defined function (as a lambda). Above, I rewrote that using a let bound function, as it's often more clear.

Comment: That makes sense now. Forgot about currying/partial application. Do you know why they would be using a partial app in this case?

Comment: Also what is the need for the Set parameter?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're just misreading the syntax. The code `s b : 'a -> 'a` doesn't mean that `b` is of type `'a`.

The right way to read it is to break it in two parts: the part before the colon is the expression, and the part after the colon is the type of that expression.

So the code `s b : 'a -> 'a` actually means that `s b` is of type `'a -> 'a`. It doesn't say anything about types of `s` or `b` individually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So s b returns a lamda that returns a type a?

Comment: Thanks! Loookjng back it now I'm not sure how I missed such a basic thing lol